# Sort MySQL colum as number if it includes characters '(' , '/' and ')'

Tags: mysql, character, sql-order-by

I think it is not possible but I prefer to ask the community.

I have a column in MySQL that is of type varchar, in which numbers and characters such as '(', '/' and ')' are stored.

The stored data correspond to a numerical order, for example:

```
1
2 (1/2), 2 (2/2)
3
4
5 (1/3), 5 (2/3), 5 (3/3)
...
```

Clearly, if I order this string through `ORDER BY 'mycol' ASC`, 1,10,11,12, .., 2,20 appear first and I would like it to be ordered as INT but I can't do the CAST as there are the characters '(' , '/' and ')'.

Can this be sorted in MySQL?

Comment: Please read the [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and use [edit] to add the expected output.

Comment: Not "for example" - provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and desired sorted output for this data. Include all possible variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
ORDER BY mycol+0 ASC
```

and anything after a space will be ignored (with a warning, which is harmless).

Comment: the problem is that being a string if it is ordered as a number, the order would be 1,10,11,12..2,20,21 ..., 3,30, ...

To solve this you can do a CAST in mysql itself

order by cast (column as unsigned) asc


But since there are '(', '/', ')' characters, this CAST is overridden

I don't know how to order a varchar as numeric but containing other characters in addition to numbers

Comment: try it!  with the `+0`, the order _will be_ 1,2,10,11,12,20,21 (ignoring the other stuff after the number)